# Database set up for multi-way relationships and form data collecting

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, join

I've posted a few questions on here and have gotten very great help and support. I'm still fairly new to programming and I'm putting together what I thought would be a simple website for the company I work at. I apologize in advance for my lengthy post/question, I just want to be thorough and clear in what I'm asking. My question is more of needing some help getting pointed in the right direction of how to get started and some best practices to be aware of. What I'm working on right now is to create a system where a user can submit a questionnaire/online form to inquire about a specific product (in this case it's a hard money loan product). The way I am planning on setting it up is to have a database with multiple tables (users, user_info, loan_app, property) and connect these together by referencing each other. I've read about table joins and I understand them conceptually but I have no idea how to implement in practice. I've had a hard time finding actual examples.

Specifically, this is what I am doing and how I am thinking it should work (correct me if I'm wrong or if there's a better way to do it):

1- the user (aka the borrower) signs in to the website. The user log in system references the user table where things like first name, last name, user name, password and user ID are stored. I have included an "active" column in this table so that when a user logs in the condition for them to get into the website is that the username and password match AND the user is activated. This way we can control on the back end certain user accounts access. I have this part working.

2- when the user registers, they only fill out the information that creates a new record in the "user" table. I have created a second table called "user_info" that will contain other data like home address, phone number email etc. But I need to be able to associate the correct record with right user. This is my first issue to wrap my head around. My thinking behind doing this instead of simply putting all this information in the user table is that for one, I might keep adding to that table and make it very big, and two for security reasons, I would like to keep the information separate. I don't know if this thought process has any merit to it though. Again, that's why I'm posting this here.

3- The user, once logged in, clicks on a button on their home screen/dashboard that will take them to the loan "pre-approval application" form, which is the questionnaire. On this form their basic information will be echoed/posted from the "user_info" table to pre-populate certain fields like first name, last name, email, phone number, address etc. So going back to #2 making sure I can associate the user with the correct record in the "user_info" table is critical. THEN, there are additional fields that the user has to fill out in order to submit the application/questionnaire. These form fields will create a new record in the "loan_app" table. This table will have a loanid column that is the primary key for that table, and an auto generated/randomized 6 or 7 digit loan number (loannum). The loanid will be a hidden value but the loan number will be like a reference number that is associated with the loan for the life of it and used for later accounting and recording purposes internally, whether or not it actually becomes a loan. The loanid, I'm assuming here, is the Foreign key in the "user" table and the userid is the Foreign key in the "loan_app" and "user_info" tables correct? If so, how do I incorporate being able to simultaneously associate all these records when the loan application/questionnaire is submitted? My thought would be write individual php scripts that does each of these things separately then have a "master" php that includes all of those individual ones that is placed as the form action associated with the submit button on the form.

Thanks for taking the time to read through this. I'd really appreciate any advice or reference material that I can read up on to learn more about this stuff. My job has a pretty crazy schedule and I travel a lot so I don't have the time to take actual classes to learn this stuff formally. I'm pretty much doing this as I go.

Also, I'm using MAMP with mysql, not sure if that helps any or not...

Answer (score 0):

The `user` table's primary key `userid` can be the primary key of the `user_info` table as well, since each user will have only one `user_info` record, right? A foreign key constraint is good to ensure only valid `userid`s get recorded in `user_info`.

The `loan_app` table can contain a denormalized relationship from `loanid` to `userid` so that each loan application is associated with a user. Again, use an FK constraint for integrity.

Don't include `loanid` in the `user` table - that would mean each user has a relationship to a single loan application. You already have the one-to-many relationship you need in the `loan_app` table.